# How to avoid Firestore document write limit when implementing an Aggregate Query?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to keep track of the number of photos I have in a Photos collection. So I want to implement an [Aggregate Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) as detailed in the linked article.

My plan is to have a Cloud Function that runs whenever a Photo document is created or deleted, and then increment or decrement the aggregate counter as needed.

This will work, but I worry about running into the 1 write/document/second limit. Say that a user adds 10 images in a single import action. That is 10 executions of the Cloud Function in more-or-less the same time, and thus 10 writes to the Aggregate Query document more-or-less at the same time.

Looking around I have seen several mentions ([like here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/sXmPclfystk)) that the  1 write/doc/sec limit is for sustained periods of constant load, not short bursts. That sounds reassuring, but it isn't really reassuring enough to convince an employer that your choice of DB is a safe and secure option if all you have to go on is that 'some guy said it was OK on Google Groups'. Is there any official sources stating that short write bursts are OK, and if so, what definitions are there for a 'short burst'?

Or are there other ways to maintain an Aggregate Query result document without also subjecting all the aggregated documents to a very restrictive 1 write / second limitation across all the aggregated documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think that you'll see a sustained write rate of more than once per second, consider dividing the aggregation up in shards. In this scenario you have N aggregation docs, and each client/function picks one at random to write to. Then when a client needs the aggregate, it reads all these subdocuments and adds them up client-side. This approach is quite well explained in the Firebase documentation on [distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters), and is also the approach used in the [distributed counter](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-counter) Firebase Extension.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is one way to reduce the impact of this issue, but it doesn't make it go away. You still run the risk of hitting the write limit if you 'go viral' and suddenly have a lot more traffic than usual. So, I'll wait a bit before I mark you as the correct answer as I'm hoping someone out there will have an answer that can scale up without development intervention.

Comment: Just in addition, I would like to share this [entry in github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/495#event-1463399312) about the limit on firestore: >This is not a hard limit that we enforce artificially, but rather something we want you to be aware of when using Cloud Firestore as it's a fundamental limitation of the system. If you sustain writes of over 1QPS to the same document, you will eventually run into this limit and your writes will be rejected.
In your case, the backend should be able to queue  the requests and execute them at a sustainable rate.